# Are futures guaranteed to start at one point?

Tags: multithreading, clojure, future, dereference

There may be other ways to do what I'll use as an example here, but that is not the point of my question.

I was doing this:

```
(future (clojure.java.shell/sh "sleep" "3" :dir "/tmp"))
```

To launch an asynchronous call to a shell script. (`"sleep 3"` is of course just an example too).

And I was wondering if the `(future...)` is called, is it guaranteed that at some point a thread is going to start and execute what's inside the future?

Or is this only guaranteed once dereferencing of the future is attempted?

(I know that a future which would always start *only* once you try to dereference it would not be very useful but that is not the point of my question: what I want to know is if it's guaranteed that a future, even if no dereferencing of that future is ever done, is guaranteed to start at one point [considering the program is still running])

Comment: That is the expectation, but I don't think you'll find a guarantee in the Java specs. There may be guarantees made by specific implementations, e.g. that thread scheduling is handled by a given OS which does perform preemptive multitasking.

Comment: @A.Webb: ah interesting... And is it guaranteed that Clojure's *future* is going to call Java's *Thread*'s *start* method?

Comment: As far I understand futures start immediately. It's independent of dereferencing. This article may help: http://www.braveclojure.com/concurrency/

Comment: Theses are implementation details, but Clojure's future <= java.util.concurrent.Future <= thread pool. We can expect concurrency, but I rather doubt you'll find explicit implementation independent guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

It's guaranteed to send future to the ExecutorService (to [clojure.lang.Agent/soloExecutor](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Agent.java))

And it's guaranteed to be sent even if you do not attempt to dereference it ([future-call source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj)).